# How to set Dependency Property declared in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to bind value from ViewModel class to custom property declared in code behind Window class. What I'm getting with this example is "The member 'FullScreen' is not recognized or is not accessible." error.

Here is MainWindow class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FullScreenProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(FullScreen), typeof(bool),
                typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), PropertyChangedCallback));

        public bool FullScreen
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(FullScreenProperty);
            set => SetValue(FullScreenProperty, value);
        }

        private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var value = (bool)e.NewValue;
            //this.GoToFullScreen(value);
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

And the XAML part:

```
<Window x:Class="WindowDependencyPropertyTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WindowDependencyPropertyTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" FullScreen="{Binding FullScreenFromVm}" >
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What would be the best way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: why do you need that ? Why not just bind:  `WindowState="{Binding Path=MyState}"` and if you do not want to use the States from VM, then you can use a converter to convert whatever object you want to use.

Comment: FullScreen was just for an example for any custom property which would run a method from extended Window class. Sorry for confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the MainWindow's `DataContext` is set to an object with a `FullScreenFromVm` property, this should work:

```
<Window x:Class="WindowDependencyPropertyTest.MainWindow" ...>
    <Window.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="local:MainWindow.FullScreen"
                    Value="{Binding FullScreenFromVm}"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
    ...
</Window>
```

Or you bind the property in the MainWindow constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SetBinding(FullScreenProperty, new Binding("FullScreenFromVm"));
}
```

Comment: It works just fine for both examples. I was also thinking about registering attached property for such a cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom window and add dependency property to it

```
public class CustomWindow : Window
{
    // propdp FullScreenFromVm ...
}
```

Then you just need to change

```
<Window ... >
```

to

```
<local:CustomWindow ... FullScreen="{Binding FullScreenFromVm}">
```

and change base class of window

```
public partial class MainWindow : CustomWindow
{
   ...
}
```

This way dependency property is available in xaml.

---

Initially I thought you could just write `<local:MainWindow ...>` to get access to defined dependency property, but unfortunately this breaks code generation, because `x:Class` expects the containing type to be a *base* class.

Comment: @Clemens, I can swear I did before posting the answer. But double-checking now it doesn't really work.

Comment: @Clemens, now it works at least, but not really a good answer. Feel free to downvote it for suggesting subclassing in wpf.